# Earthquake json/js coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I an trying to code a json script that retrieves the latest recent earthquakes. This is working fine.

I am having trouble trying to format the dates and times. Also for magnitude and depth lines, I only need the first 3 characters(numbers).
Example page can be found here : https://www.feildingweather.com/quakes/

My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  returnQuakes(4);

});


function returnNews() {
  var url = 'https://api.geonet.org.nz/news/geonet';

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data.feed, function(key, val) {
      items.push("<li>" + "<a target='_blank' " + "href='" + val.link + "'>" + val.title + "</a>" + "</li>");
    });

    $("<ul/>", {
      "class": "list",
      html: items.join("")
    }).appendTo("#news");
  });
}


function returnQuakes(greaterThan) {
  var url = 'https://api.geonet.org.nz/quake?MMI=' + greaterThan;

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data.features, function(key, val) {
      var dateTime = new Date(Date.parse(val.properties.time));
      console.log(dateTime.getDate() + "/" + dateTime.getMonth() + "/" + dateTime.getFullYear() + " " + dateTime.getHours());

      items.push("<li class='title'>" +
        val.properties.locality +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li>Magnitude: " + val.properties.magnitude + "</li>" +
        "<li>Depth: " + val.properties.depth + "</li>" +
        "<li>Time: " + val.properties.time + "</li>" +
        "</ul></li>");
    });

    $("<ul/>", {
      "class": "list",
      html: items.join("")
    }).appendTo("#quakes");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quakes"></div>
```

Comment: you should explain why you are having trouble formatting the date and times, what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything is working fine and a few of these nuances could be solved by reading some doc

To format a [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as `day/month/year` with the time you can do the following using date.[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
var date = new Date();

// I guessed en-GB for your locale
var formatted = date.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  hour12: true
})

console.log(formatted)
```

To get your magnitude and Depth rounded to 2 decimals you can use [toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). Note: keep in mind toFixed returns a `string`.

```js
var depth = 11.95286655
var magnitude = 4.00689878;
console.log(`Depth: ${depth.toFixed(2)}
Magnitude: ${magnitude.toFixed(2)}`);
```